# How ReactJS display fetch response onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to generate a random user information when pressing the button, and display the information above the button. In ProfilePanel.js, I created a avatar and user constants, which will use to show the information. In index.js, the avatar constant works for that since it doesn't need to use the Button. however, for user constant, it doesn't work. In below's code, I am fetching a API data to display user name, but it didn't show anything, I am not sure where wrong, is something wrong in Button.js or index.js. and how can I fix it. Can somebody help me out?

```
<Button title="name" >
<p key={contact.name} user={contact.name}></p>
</Button>
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Panel from "./ProfilePanel";
import axios from 'axios';
import './index.css';
import Button from './Button';

const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      contacts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchdata();
  }

  fetchdata() {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ contacts: res.data.results});
      });
  }

  render(){
    const {contacts} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="panel">
          {contacts.map(contact => (
          <div class="panel">
            <Panel
              key={contact.picture} avatar={contact.picture.medium}
            />
            <li class="flex-container">
              <Button title="name" >
                <p key={contact.name} user={contact.name}></p>
              </Button>
              <Button title="location" onClick={this.fetchdata}> 
              </Button>
              <Button key={contact.email} title="email">
              </Button>
              <Button key={contact.phone} title="phone">
              </Button>
              <Button key={contact.login.password} title="password">
              </Button>
            </li>
          </div>
            ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

ProfilePanel.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import './index.css';
import Button from './Button';

const style={
  borderRadius: 150,
  margin: 15,
}

class Panel extends Component {

  render() {
    const { avatar,  user } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="Panel">
        <div class="panels">
          <div className="avatar">
            <img src={avatar} class="imageStyle" alt="" width={"200%"} height={"auto"}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          <h2 className="user">{user}</h2>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Panel;
```

Button.js

```
import './index.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Button extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open:false,
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    const { title } = this.props;
    const {open} = this.state;
    return (
      <button className={` ${open ? 'open' : ''}`} 
      class='button' onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
        <div className="panel-heading">
          <h2 class='buttoncenter'>{title}</h2>
        </div>
      </button>
    );
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      open: this.state.open
    })
  }
  }

  export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing state in the handle click. You need to set open to true;

```
handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
     open: true
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your user information in index.js. I think you have missed to pass the user props to the panel component, so that it shows the avatar alone. Without passing the users props, you are trying to destructure there in panel component.

```
//index.js should be like this

render(){
    const {contacts} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="panel">
          {contacts.map(contact => (
          <div class="panel">
            <Panel
              key={contact.picture} user={contact.name} avatar={contact.picture.medium}
            />
            <li class="flex-container">
              <Button title="name" >
                <p key={contact.name} user={contact.name}></p>
              </Button>
              <Button title="location" onClick={this.fetchdata}> 
              </Button>
              <Button key={contact.email} title="email">
              </Button>
              <Button key={contact.phone} title="phone">
              </Button>
              <Button key={contact.login.password} title="password">
              </Button>
            </li>
          </div>
            ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: If I add user={contact.name} in the <Panel>, the project show                      
" Invariant Violation. Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, first, last}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in h2 (created by Panel)
    in div (created by Panel)
    in div (created by Panel)
    in Panel (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App "